# Flask, get local time

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a Flask app in Python and I would like to save the user local time.

I thought of using this

```
time.strftime('%A %B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But this is giving me the server local time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> For a web application, flask is responsible for server side only.

Your purpose can be achieved by using javascript to get client side time and passing it to server.

**Folder structure**

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/getTime", methods=['GET'])
def getTime():
    print("browser time: ", request.args.get("time"))
    print("server time : ", time.strftime('%A %B, %d %Y %H:%M:%S'));
    return "Done"
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<script> 
function sendTimeToServer(){
    var time = new Date();
    var i = document.createElement("img");
    i.src = "/getTime?time=" + time;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
}
</script>
<button onclick="sendTimeToServer()">update time</button>
<div id="time">Time: </div>
```

**Example result on console**

```
# 1. open browser: http://127.0.0.1:5000
# 2. click "update time" button

 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2016 19:58:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
browser time:  Tue Nov 01 2016 19:58:37 GMT 0800 (CST)
server time:   Tuesday November, 01 2016 19:58:37
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2016 19:58:37] "GET /getTime?time=Tue%20Nov%2001%202016%2019:58:37%20GMT+0800%20(CST) HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score -3):

using client side to get date is not a good way as it's not safe.
I think best way is to update your local server time to your time zone and use [Python datetime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime) lib to get current time.
Users can change your js file and pass wrong date time to your server!

Comment: This isn't good advice - servers should nearly always be set to UTC. And the poster is asking for _user_ timezone - how does setting server TZ to local help? The user may be in a different timezone. And obviously, user timezone would never be used for core server functions. More like displaying a clock or naming a file, something client side.